# How to generate shared library(.so) file for a C++ program that contains protobuf library

Tags: c++, api, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers, grpc

So I have a C++ file named `admv2_api.cc` (and `admv2_api.h` of course). Inside it I `#include` a lot of generated code from protobuf. Those generated codes are related to some `message` and gRPC `service` definitions. I defined some APIs (like `.runServer()`) in `admv2_api.cc` so that people who don't know the details of gRPC can still use it to set up server and send messages, etc.

Now I want to generate a .so file for `admv2_api.cc` so that people can just link their programs against this .so file and use the APIs I defined in `admv2_api.cc`. Any insights on how to do this?

A complete tree of the files I have is here:

```
admv2_api.cc
    -- #includes transport.grpc.pb.cc(generated file, contains definition of message and service)
    -- #includes UX.grpc.pb.cc(generated file, contains definition of message)
```

One try I had done:

Generate .so file like this:

```
admv2_api.so: $(OBJS_GRPCS) $(OBJS_CCS) admv2_api.o
    g++ -std=c++11 $^ $(LDFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o $@
%.o: %.cc
    g++ -std=c++11 $< -c -fPIC -o $@
```

Where `$(OBJS_GRPCS)` is just `transport.grpc.pb.o UX.grpc.pb.o` and `$(OBJS_CCS)` is `transport.pb.o UX.pb.o`. `$(LDFLAGS)` is flags related to `grpc/protobuf`, which is `-L/usr/local/lib 'pkg-config --libs grpc++' -lgrpc++_reflection -lprotobuf -lpthread`

And then I rename `admv2_api.so` to `libadmv2_api.so` and put it into `/usr/lib`.

Then I wrote a simple test program named `main.cc`. Compile it:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cc -I /path/to/admv2_api.h/ -ladmv2_api -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs grpc++` -lgrpc++_reflection -lprotobuf -lpthread -ldl -o main
```

It compiled without error. However, when I ran `./main`, it has the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: admv2_api.so
  Referenced from: /Users/some/path/so-test/main/./main
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: For shared library loading failures, you might consider running strace to see what files it's trying to load and where.  It's a noisy output but you should see everything it tries.  The error message you posted says "admv2_api.so" not found, but you said your renamed it to have the "lib" prefix.  Doublecheck it's loading the filename you expect.  Also, check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes where the library is.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis Thank you for your comments. I will try strace. But for the lib renaming, I think all library files in /usr/lib should be renamed as "lib" + "library name" + ".so, etc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries it seems to me that this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: admv2_api.so
  Referenced from: /Users/some/path/so-test/main/./main
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

is a Mac OS issue. I tested the same code on a linux server and it worked just fine.

Comment: macos is a bit odd. It uses Mach-O binary format, not ELF (as Linux and many other OSes do). You probably want to create a dylib, or maybe a bundle.